# Google Translate API for iPhone - UTF8 problem in Chinese Translation

Tags: iphone, google-translate

I've tested a workable translation API url by:

http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=%E5%BB%A3%E5%A0%B4&langpair=zh|zh-CN

And it returns the correct result as the following which is in JSON format:

{"sentences":[{"trans":"广场","orig":"廣場","translit":"Guǎngchǎng"}],"src":"zh-CN"}

However, when I try to use this function in XCode, I experienced this problem ...
Here is my code:

NSData *data;

```
NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/translate_a/t?client=t&text=%@&langpair=zh|zh-CN",qText];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"http"
                                      host:@"translate.google.com"
                                      path:urlPath];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //Problem's here. It returns nil.
NSLog(result);
```

Initially I guessed it's encoding problem so I tried other encoding as well (NSISOLatin1StringEncoding) , but I got wrong answer: {"sentences":[{"trans":"ã  ","orig":"ã ","translit":"Tu¨¯   "}],"src":"zh-CN"}

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the error object? If an error occurs, this call will just set the error object and continue - it won't crash/throw like a normal error.

Try something like this after the sendSynchronousRequest call:

```
if (error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

This should give more details if an error occurred.